# Convert UTC Time to Multiple Time zones

Tags: sql-server, timezone

The below SQL will convert the UTC time to my local time in BRISBANE, Australia.
I would like to get the Local time in Sydney which is 1 hour ahead of Brisbane time considering the DST

```
SELECT  
GETUTCDATE() AS UTCTime,
CAST(GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'E. Australia Standard Time'  AS DATETIME2(2))    AS BrisbaneTime
```

Need some assistance in getting the local time in Sydney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the possible timezones are defined in the sys.time_zone_info system table.  From there you can select the appropriate timeone to use.

You would use the same query but with the other timezone